# If $X \sim N\left(\mu_x,\sigma^{2}_x\right)$ and $Y \sim N\left(\mu_y,\sigma^{2}_y\right) $ than what is $Y \mid X=x$?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, conditional-probability

Suppose $X \sim N\left(\mu_x,\sigma^{2}_x\right)$ and $Y \sim N\left(\mu_y,\sigma^{2}_y\right)$ then $Y \mid X=x\sim N\left(\mu_{y}+\rho\frac{\sigma_{y}}{\sigma_{x}} (x-\mu_x), \sigma_{y}^2\left(1-\rho^2\right)\right)$.

My question is:

- How to show that  $Y \mid X=x$ is also Normal distributed
- How to show the joint PDF of $Y \mid X=x$ with using the formula $f_{Y \mid X=x}(y):=\frac{f(x, y)}{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x, t) d t}$.

Comment: $f(x,y)$ is not given and the question does not make sense.

Comment: From what you write, I'm guessing the joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$ is a bivariate normal with mean $(\mu_1, \mu_2)^T$ and covariance matrix $\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}\sigma_x^2 & \rho \sigma_x \sigma_y \\\rho \sigma_x \sigma_y & \sigma_y^2\end{smallmatrix}\bigr)$, isn't it? What have you tried next? The usual strategy is to start from your second point, write the full expression of the PDFs and simplify it down to a new normal-like expression. Where are you encountering difficulties?

Comment: You probably forgot to tell us that $(X,Y)$ is Gaussian with correlation coefficient $\rho.$

Answer (score 1):

If the joint distribution of $$ and $$ is a bivariate normal with mean $\mu := (\mu_{x},\mu_{y})^{T}$ and covariance matrix $\Sigma := \big(\begin{smallmatrix}
  \sigma_{x}^{2} & \rho \sigma_{x} \sigma_{y}\\
   \rho \sigma_{x} \sigma_{y} & \sigma_{y}^{2}
\end{smallmatrix}\big)$
then the problem can be solved by some rather straightforward but tedious calculations.
For $f(x,y)$ we use the density of the Multivariate normal distribution ([link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution)). First we calculate the inverse of $\Sigma$ since its a $2 \times 2$ matrix this can be done easily. We find,
$$ \Sigma^{-1}= \frac{1}{(1-\rho^{2})\sigma_{x}^{2}\sigma_{y}^{2}}\begin{pmatrix}
 \sigma_{y}^{2} & -\rho \sigma_{x} \sigma_{y}\\
   -\rho \sigma_{x} \sigma_{y} & \sigma_{x}^{2}
\end{pmatrix}.$$
Then using the joint density we have,
$$ f(x,y) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{(2\pi)^{2}(1-\rho^{2})\sigma_{x}^{2}\sigma_{y}^{2}}}\exp{\left(-\frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix}
 x - \mu_{x} \\
    y - \mu_{y} 
\end{pmatrix}^{T}\Sigma^{-1}\begin{pmatrix}
 x - \mu_{x} \\
    y - \mu_{y} 
\end{pmatrix}\right)}.$$
We now solve the
$$ \begin{pmatrix}
 x - \mu_{x} \\
    y - \mu_{y} 
\end{pmatrix}^{T}\Sigma^{-1}\begin{pmatrix}
 x - \mu_{x} \\
    y - \mu_{y} 
\end{pmatrix} = \frac{\sigma_{y}^{2}(x-\mu_{x})^{2}-2\rho\sigma_{x}\sigma_{y}(x-\mu_{x})(y-\mu_{y})+\sigma_{x}^{2}(y-\mu_{y})^{2}}{(1-\rho^{2})\sigma_{x}^{2}\sigma_{y}^{2}}$$

Factoring out everything that does not depend on $y$ and doing quadratic expansion yields
\begin{align*}
\int_{-\infty}^{-\infty}f(x,t)dt &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma_{x}}}\exp{-\frac{1}{2}\frac{\sigma_{y}^{2}(x-\mu_{x})^{2}+2\rho\sigma_{x}\sigma_{y}\mu_{y}-\mu_{y}^{2}+2\mu_{y}\rho\sigma_{x}\sigma_{y}(x-\mu_{x})-\rho^{2}\sigma_{y}^{2}(x-\mu_{x})^{2}}{(1-\rho^{2})\sigma_{x}^{2}\sigma_{y}^{2}}} \\
& \left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi(1-\rho^{2})\sigma_{y}^{2}}}\int_{-\infty}^{-\infty} \exp{-\frac{1}{2}\frac{\left(t - \mu_{y} -\rho \frac{\sigma_{y}}{\sigma{x}}(x-\mu_{x}) \right)^{2}}{(1-\rho^{2})\sigma_{y}^{2}}}dt\right) \\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma_{x}}}\exp{-\frac{1}{2}\frac{\sigma_{y}^{2}(x-\mu_{x})^{2}+2\rho\sigma_{x}\sigma_{y}\mu_{y}-\mu_{y}^{2}+2\mu_{y}\rho\sigma_{x}\sigma_{y}(x-\mu_{x})-\rho^{2}\sigma_{y}^{2}(x-\mu_{x})^{2}}{(1-\rho^{2})\sigma_{x}^{2}\sigma_{y}^{2}}}. 
\end{align*}
Now we can plug this into the formula $f_{Y \mid X=x}(y):=\frac{f(x, y)}{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x, t) d t}.$
We find,
\begin{align*}
f_{Y \mid X=x}(y)&= \frac{f(x, y)}{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x, t) d t} \\
&= \frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt{(2\pi)^{2}(1-\rho^{2})\sigma_{x}^{2}\sigma_{y}^{2}}}\exp{-\frac{1}{2}}\frac{\sigma_{y}^{2}(x-\mu_{x})^{2}-2\rho\sigma_{x}\sigma_{y}(x-\mu_{x})(y-\mu_{y})+\sigma_{x}^{2}(y-\mu_{y})^{2}}{(1-\rho^{2})\sigma_{x}^{2}\sigma_{y}^{2}}}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma_{x}}}\exp{-\frac{1}{2}\frac{\sigma_{y}^{2}(x-\mu_{x})^{2}+2\rho\sigma_{x}\sigma_{y}\mu_{y}-\mu_{y}^{2}+2\mu_{y}\rho\sigma_{x}\sigma_{y}(x-\mu_{x})-\rho^{2}\sigma_{y}^{2}(x-\mu_{x})^{2}}{(1-\rho^{2})\sigma_{x}^{2}\sigma_{y}^{2}}}} \\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi(1-\rho^{2})\sigma_{y}^{2}}}\exp{-\frac{1}{2}\frac{y^2-2y\mu_{y}+2y\rho \frac{\sigma_{y}}{\sigma_{x}}(x-\mu_{x})+\mu_{y}^{2}-2\mu_{y}\rho \frac{\sigma_{y}}{\sigma_{x}}(x-\mu_{x})+\rho^{2} \frac{\sigma^{2}_{y}}{\sigma^{2}_{x}}(x-\mu_{x})^{2}}{(1-\rho^{2})^{2}\sigma_{y}^{2}}} \\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi(1-\rho^{2})\sigma_{y}^{2}}}\exp{-\frac{1}{2}\frac{\left(y-\mu_{y}+\rho \frac{\sigma_{y}}{\sigma_{x}}(x-\mu_{x})\right)^{2}}{(1-\rho^{2})^{2}\sigma_{y}^{2}}} \\
&= 
\end{align*}
Where the last step is the density of a normally distributed one dimensional random variable with
$$ Y \mid X=x \sim N\left(\mu_y+\rho \frac{\sigma_y}{\sigma_x}\left(x-\mu_x\right), \sigma_y^2\left(1-\rho^2\right)\right).$$

Comment: I think there's a mistake - you should be able to simplify $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x,t) dt$ into $f_X(x)$, but it looks like you have some extra terms.

Comment: @dvdgrgrtt you need the extra terms. (There might be a typo at some intermediate result though, the terms are quite cumbersome.) In general its not possible to simplify $\int_{\infty}^{\infty}f(x,t)dt$ into $f_{X}(x)$. The equation $\int_{\infty}^{\infty}f(x,t)dt=f_{X}(x)$ only holds when $X,Y$ are independent. Then $\rho=0$ and the claim becomes $Y \mid X=x \sim Y$, trivial in this case. You can see that you need extra terms by solving the claim backward. Start with the density of $N\left(\mu_y+\rho \frac{\sigma_y}{\sigma_x}\left(x-\mu_x\right), \sigma_y^2\left(1-\rho^2\right)\right) $

Comment: I don't agree - have a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marginal_distribution#Marginal_probability_density_function). If $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then $f(x,y)=f_X(x) f_Y(y)$, as you can easily check in the Gaussian case by setting $\rho=0$. Regarding the conditional distribution, we have $f_{Y|X=x}(y)=f(x,y)/f_X(x)$ and, indeed under independence, $f_{Y|X=x}(y)=f_X(x)f_Y(y)/f_X(x)=f_Y(y)$.

Comment: @dvdgrgtt Yes, I agree with your last comment. That is what I was trying to say as well. But in your problem, there is no mention of $X,Y$ being independent. It also makes no sense to assume it additionally, since the claim you want to prove, namely $Y \mid X=x \sim N\left(\mu_y+\rho \frac{\sigma_y}{\sigma_x}\left(x-\mu_x\right), \sigma_y^2\left(1-\rho^2\right)\right)$, holds for non-independent bivariate normally distributed $X,Y$. But then you need the extra terms to account for the correlation structure.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't express myself correctly. The part on independent variables is an extra, just to show how the problem simplifies in that special case. But the fact that  $f_X(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(x,t) dt$ holds true in general and, if you revise your calculations, you'll see that it works here.